# Fastest way to set a css property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm busy creating a resizer, but on reloading it first switches from 100% until loading the cookie and setting the width to something fixed:

```
//set width from cookie, unfortunately we need todo this on docready because #main-container is not done rendering -_-
var width = $.cookie("width");
// Set the user's selection for the left column
if (width != null) {
    if (width == "fluid") {
        alert("fluid!");
        $('#main-container').addClass('width-fluid');
    } else {
        $('#main-container').addClass('width-fixed');
    }
} else {
    $('#main-container').addClass('width-fixed');
};
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: The `!= null` seems redundant, a single if-else against `width == "fluid"` will do the same. Also, you're currently adding a class, not setting a CSS property. They're two different things.

Comment: you gave us js and told us what it does...  you have better odds of getting a correct answer if we also have the html and know what you WANT it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the default css property "height" and "width" as 0 inline or in a external css file, then when the cookie is loaded, it will set it to what you want.

ex. of inline default css (before js affects it)

```
<element style="height:0px;width:0px;" />
```

I'm assuming you're dealing with a block-level element (image), if not you might want to also set the element to "display:block" so it will respect the height and width.

Comment: I tried this but it's very late upon injecting. I'm looking for something that will work outside docready and isn't dependable on the full render of #main-container.

Comment: again, we're having to guess at what you WANT it to do.  I'm assuming from this comment, you're wanting it to load the cookie width before even displaying the page?  the more code you can provide the better (html/css/js)

Answer (score 0):

You can set specific css properties using jQuery with the following :

```
$("#selector").css("property-name", value);
```

so for width, you would just use:

```
$("#main-container").css("width", value);
```

Comment: You keep saying "too slow" but you don't specifically say why or what your requirements are. Post a complete working sample page (via jsfiddle perhaps) and then describe what you don't like about how it works.